# Setting up proxy server on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, proxy, server, ip

I am trying to set up a proxy server on my iPhone. I am doing this manual by looking up a proxy server Ip and port from Google and use this as proxy settings on my iPhone.

But when I do this and I try to connect to a random url, it is taking too long and at the end it says: can't open this page because the network is disconnected.

I have tried like 30 different IPs and ports from multiple websites and got none of them worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up non-working proxy servers.
Almost all "best 100 free public proxy servers" lists are fake or outdated.

The only option to guarantee that proxy is working is to make your own proxy. 
I used Amazon free tier instance with Linux and installed proxy on it. It is free for one year.